# How to show current page using CSS? .current_link not working

Tags: css, hyperlink

I'm trying to show the current page link in a different color. I've found other answers that will do this, but its still not working. I'm using a class of current_link on the respective links of each page. I also found an answer that said to apply the !important tag to the color rule but that didn't do anything. I'm thinking I have something small wrong or that I'm not aware of. Maybe some kind of ordering rule.
Here's the CSS rules relative to my links. As you can see I have .current_link at the top (I figured this would get rid of any ordering/over riding issues). The relative HTML naming will follow.

```
.current_link {
    color: #00AD26;
}

#main_nav a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #00A3E6;
}
#main_nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #A8EDFF;
}
#main_nav a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00B7FF;
}


a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #00A3E6;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00B7FF;
}
```

Relative HTML from one of the pages.

```
<ul id="main_nav" class="grid_5 prefix_9">
    <li id="home" class="current_link"><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
#main_nav li.current_link a {
    color: #00AD26;
}
```

This will overrule the other selectors and avoids using `!important`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks for all of your answers and your swiftness. I tried everything I've found before this. Including being more specific, and applying '!important' to the rule. The thing that made the difference was I had put a space between the li and '.current_link' why do they need to be together? Aren't they 2 different selectors so should be seperated? Also is it the specificness that will over rule other selectors? Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. The reason it's `li.current_link` is because you want to target an `li` element with the class `current_link`. If you separate them then you're actually targeting an element with the class `current_link` inside the `li`. To really understand which selectors overrule others I recommend this article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ - it's very detailed and explains it much clearer than I could. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your `.current_link` matches the `<li>`.
The `<a>` inside the `<li>` overrides the color it inherits from its parent element.

You need to apply the color to the `<a>` itself, either by moving the class or by changing the selector to select `<a>` elements inside the `<li>`.

Also, *lower* rules override earlier ones (if they have the same specificity).

Comment: Also be sure that the .current_link a selector has a higher level of specificity over the more generic link colour styles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking it was the other way around. That higher rules would override the lower.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.current_link a {
    color: #00AD26 !important;
}
```

Comment: The use of !important can be avoided by being more specific with the selector.